# First Formula Copied to All Cells in Column

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, excel-interop

We are using a multidimensional array to set the formulas and values for a column range of the same dimension. The problem we are seeing is that no matter what values are in the array, the column is copying the first formula in every cell in the column.
ex:

```
var values = new object[3,1];
values[0,0] = "=$A$2";
values[1,0] = 3;
values[2,0] = 4;

range.Formula = values;
```

When we look in the spreadsheet we see the formula "=$A$2" in each cell in the column. If we set the first value in the multidimensional array to not be a formula everything works fine. Am I missing something?

**Edit**
This happens with Excel 2010.

Comment: What does `range` represent here?

Comment: The range is the data body range for a list object.

Comment: And the dimensions of `range` match with `values` ?

Comment: Yep. Everything matches up. The table is 3 rows with 1 column each.

Comment: You need to switch your dimensions in `values` - should be `[row, column]` not `[column,row]`

Comment: I corrected the edit, but the actual code has the correct dimensions. I can't  use the actual source here due to company policies. The issue still remains.

Comment: Please don't post "non-code" in questions: it doesn't help you, and it leads to people spending time on non-issues.

Comment: What do you mean "non-code"? It is a port of the code with minor changes to illustrate the issue. The issue still happens with the code in my question.

Comment: Instead of range.Formula, does range.FormulaArray work?

Comment: range.FormulaArray does work, but I don't think this is the correct use of FormulaArray as it asks for R1C1 notation.

Comment: Glad it works! From what I gather, the R1C1 notation is requested but it is still able to work with A1 notation.

Comment: I still don't feel like that is the right answer. I shouldn't have different results just because a formula is the first element in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out things work if I set the formulas using:

```
range.FormulaArray = values;
```